# Why DateTime.TryParseExact is not working?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I am reading date from Excel and stored it in a variable **In_Date**,
formats with which the date is to be compared is stored in **Valid_Date_Formats**

**In_Date** = "08/01/2020 00:00:00"

**Valid_Date_Formats** is an array which stores multiple date formats.

[image]

I am checking the format in if condition but it always fails.

```
If(DateTime.TryParseExact(In_Date, Valid_Date_Formats,
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
    System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None,
    DateTime_PlaceHolder))
```

What am I doing wrong here.

Comment: Maybe i'm missing something but the sample date "In_Date = "08/01/2020 00:00:00" is formatted MM/dd/yyyy... and I don't see that format in your valid format array. Besides that I don't see any time format on your valid formats array which would matter if your date included the time.

Comment: In your Valid_Date_Formats I can't see hours and minutes.

Comment: @FernandoG I added it, it still fails

Comment: @StefanoBalzarotti do I need to add that as well?

Comment: `TryParseExact` means *match exactly the provided format*. All your formats do not include the Time part. If you use InvariantCulture, use the `MM/dd/yyyy ...` format, or you'll get Month/Day mismatches and related exceptions. Otherwise, use the local settings if the Date format is different (as in `dd/MM/yyyy`).

Comment: You might consider using `TryParse` first, and only do `ParseExact` with any odd inputs you expect. The input string that's causing you problems here works fine if you just do `var x = DateTime.Parse("08/01/2020 00:00:00");`. Same with a lot of the formats you're specifying manually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The input string has the following format: `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss`, which is missing from `Valid_Date_Formats`. (I'm assuming the `08` here is the day, because all your other formats start with the date part.)

The following returns the correct date:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("08/01/2020 00:00:00", new[] { "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss" }, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None)
```

In response to your comment: I'm not aware of a built-in method that would tell you which exact format string was used. If you really need to find out, I guess you could traverse the formats until you find a match:

```
string[] formats = new[] { "dd/MM/yyyy", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss" };
string input = "08/01/2020 00:00:00";

string usedFormat = null;
DateTime date;

foreach (string format in formats)
{
    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(input, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
    {
        usedFormat = format;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to detect the format in code, then parse the string yourself by examining each character in a loop. Also, if you don't care about the time portion, then you could remove it from the input string before calling `ParseExact`

Comment: @Rufus L, did you find out if it's okay to remove the time from the input string before parsing? I would think that should be fine, but I'm having trouble with parsing my string.

Comment: @KrisBunda What do you mean by *"if it's okay"*? Why would it not be ok? Sounds like you may want to ask a new question and post the code that isn't working as you expect it to.

Answer (score 1):

In my particular case it seems like an undocumented breaking bugfix somewhere in the DotNet SDK 3.1 to 7.0 upgrade.

I was originally using Dotnet SDK 3.1 but after Alpine Linux (previously Debian) along SDK 7 upgrade the `DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, "g", enUS.....)` now does not parse my date value for example `4/13/2020 5:30:13 PM` which worked in 3.1 just fine. In SDK7 I had to changed the format from `"g"` to `"M/d/yyyy h:m:s tt"` exact pattern match and it worked.

I am tagging the Alpine upgrade thread since anybody who might encounter this side effect of SDK upgrade can find the other thread helpful. [Running .NET 6 project in Docker throws Globalization.CultureNotFoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71045784/running-net-6-project-in-docker-throws-globalization-culturenotfoundexception)